# I have done my codes but the page not working

Tags: php, laravel

my web that I have coded not uploaded as I expected it show me the directory instead of my page.

[image: that's what I get]

Comment: You need to do `php artisan serve` on the command line. Read the laravel docs

Comment: I suspect another cause, since your root directory should be the public folder. Can give us more information about your environment (are you using Apache? Nginx? Homestead? Sail? None of them?)

Answer (score 0):

when you work in Zamp software, you create a folder in the htdocs folder and then drop your projects in it. For example, if the folder name in the htdocs folder is test and the project name is one, you should go to localhost / test / one. php When you go to this path, the project runs directly. There is another way that you went this way. Write localhost / index, which you opened correctly. Now look for the name of your project in this section and click on it. But if there is no project or the project does not load, there is something wrong with your workplace. Example of code errors and your work path I hope this article has helped you